# No directive found with exportAs 'matMenu' in angular 16

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am facing an error in my Angular application:

```
No directive found with exportAs 'matMenu'
```

Here is my code:

```
<mat-menu #failedDiscussion="matMenu">
```

I have imported and exported in the module:

```
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { TestComponent } from './components/test.component';

declarations: [
 TestComponent
],
imports: [
  MatMenuModule
]
```

Is there anything else that is required?

Comment: It works fine for me in Angular 16 using the examples from the docs: https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples#menu-overview. Also I use this syntax in an Angular 16 project and it works just fine. Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the module MatMenuModule in to app.module.ts and not in your components